# server to server DDP.connect stuck connecting/waiting

Tags: meteor, ddp

My log form meteor shell, on meteor 1.6... same issue with 1.1 and 1.4

```
> conn.status()
{ status: 'connecting', connected: false, retryCount: 1 }
> conn.status()
{ status: 'connecting', connected: false, retryCount: 1 }
> conn.status()
{ status: 'connecting', connected: false, retryCount: 1 }
> conn.status()
{ status: 'connecting', connected: false, retryCount: 2 }
> conn.status()
{ status: 'connecting', connected: false, retryCount: 3 }
> conn.status()
{ status: 'waiting',
  connected: false,
  retryCount: 5,
  retryTime: 1496079626340.3574 }
> conn.status()
{ status: 'waiting',
  connected: false,
  retryCount: 5,
  retryTime: 1496079626340.3574 }
> .reload
Server unavailable (waiting to reconnect)
```

where `conn = DDP.connect('127.0.0.1:3000');`... the address loads on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

does `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` output anything? This is likely a proxy issue with the `http_proxy` environment var without setting `no_proxy` appropriately.

If you set `no_proxy` you should get a connection, here what mine looks like

```
/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh 
export http_proxy="http://192.168.43.1:8080"
export https_proxy="http://192.168.43.1:8080"
export all_proxy="socks5://192.168.43.1:1080"
export no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1, ::1, 192.168.43.1"
```

no proxy lists host suffixes, not subnets or wildcards for curl. curl and pacman support all_proxy